The $27$ dots problem
Here is a generalization of the well-known Nine dots puzzle to $3$ dimensions, where we introduce a new constraint (it is just a particular case of a more general problem that I have recently shared on MO, so let us name it the 27 dots problem).
27 dots problem: Let the $27$ points $\{0,1,2\} \times \{0,1,2\} \times \{0,1,2\} \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ be given in the Euclidean space (i.e., the set of points that we have to connect is $\{(0,0,0), (0,0,1), (0,0,2), (0,1,0), (0,1,1), (0,1,2), (0,2,0), (0,2,1), (0,2,2), (1,0,0), (1,0,1), (1,0,2), (1,1,0), (1,1,1), (1,1,2),(1,2,0), (1,2,1), (1,2,2), (2,0,0), (2,0,1), (2,0,2), (2,1,0), (2,1,1), (2,1,2), (2,2,0), (2,2,1), (2,2,2)\}).$
Our goal is to visit (at least once) all the $27$ points by using a polygonal chain consisting of only $13$ line segments connected at their endpoints (it can be a mere trail since we are not required to perform a circuit). What is the shortest total Euclidean length of such a $13$-link polygonal chain?
My current upper bound is $2 \cdot \big(9+5 \cdot \sqrt{2}+2 \cdot \sqrt{3} \big) \approx 39.07$, which comes from $$(2,1,1)-(0,3,1)-(0,0,1)-(2,0,1)-(0,2,-1)-(3,2,2)-(-1,2,2)-(2,-1,2)-(2,2,2)-(0,0,2)-(2,2,0)-(2,0,0)-(0,0,0)-(0,2,0),$$ but I am confident that we can still lower down this value pretty much.
P.S.
It is worth pointing out that this is not a casual problem since $13$ is the proven minimum number of edges for a polygonal chain covering the given set of $27$ points (the outcome easily follows as a particular case of my Theorem 2.1). On the other hand, we can easily connect all the nodes of the mentioned $3 \times 3 \times 3$ grid by using a spanning path consisting of $15$ links and whose total Euclidean length is just $3^3-1$ (e.g., a valid spanning path with $15$ line segments is given by $$(1,1,2)-(1,1,0)-(1,2,0)-(1,2,2)-(0,2,2)-(0,0,2)-(2,0,2)-(2,2,2)-(2,2,0)-(2,0,0)-(0,0,0)-(0,2,0)-(0,2,1)-(0,0,1)-(2,0,1)-(2,1,1)$$ and its total Euclidean length provides us a trivial lower bound for the stated problem).

Do you require the chain to use exactly $13$ segments? Would a path with more segments but shorter total length be of interest?

We need to use only polygonal chains with exactly $13$ line segments since I proved that any minimum-link covering trail for given $k$-dimensional regular grids of the form ${0,1,2}^k$ must have exactly $\frac{3^k-1}{2}$ edges (I can provide the references if you are interested in the topic). Now, it is trivial to point out that a spanning path of $17$ segments has minimal total Euclidean distance (i.e., $3^3-1$), matching the minimum total Euclidean distance of any forest covering the given set of $27$ points. Thus the mentioned variation of the original problem wouldn't be of any interest.

Just added a P.S. to clarify why it is crucial to consider only polygonal chains with $13$ edges (or maybe $14$ as the only acceptable nontrivial hybrid configuration).
